# Untraced magic inside the Dursley house?

Tags: harry-potter

I have the following question:

As we very well know, the Ministry of Magic can detect magic in proximity of minors (like the hovercharm in **Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets** or the Patronus in **Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix**), but not the caster of the magical spell. So why does the ministry *not* accuse Harry of doing magic in the following scenes?

1. **Goblet of Fire**: Mr. Weasly blows up the Dursleys' living room
2. **Order of Phoenix**: Tonks helps Harry with his luggage using several magic spells
   *(One would think that this is a rather important fact, as Harry has to face the court due to the prior Patronus-spell)*

---

*I think there was one more scene, but I cannot remember it at the moment*

Comment: goblet of fire, mr weasly had made it known he was gathering harry, and in order of the phoenix we can guess a similar request was made,handled, or covered up due to the fact that kingsly shacklebolt was there.

Comment: your 3rd one would be right before Harry's birthday when they pick him up in the 7th book.

Comment: @Himarm: Thank you very much, Sir for the quick reply. I guess you are right on your first comment :) I will look up the third scene when I come back home and notify you, when I have found it

Comment: @Himarm - sorry, that's wrong. Book 7 (in Moody's voice) very specifically discusses NOT doing magic because of the Trace.

Comment: @DVK sorry should have clarified, the 3rd scene he was thinking of most likely would have been from book 7, since there were other wizards in his house, however, as you said they didnt cast spells just took the polyjuice potion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Underage magic restriction isn't (in spirit) mainly about the underage part - it's about magic being revealed to Muggles.

   As such:

   - Mr Weasley only did magic in front of Dursleys, who already know
   - Tonks only did magic in front of Harry.
2. As @Himarm mentions, Mr. Weasley was in Harry's house **Officially** (known to the MoM), and so was Tonks

   (Arthur had to get special permission to connect Dursley's house to Floo network).

Comment: though he did get special permission due to pulling some strings(did so and so some favors), so it may or may not have "actually" been approved through all channels haha.